# Getting Average number based on UserID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is a follow up to a previous post. I'm trying to get the average days each person took to close all of their transactions in a month. Each person has 200+ transactions each month and we're only going by the open date to Invoice date, so we don't have to worry about a transaction that took place the following month.

I was able to use a CASE statement change anything with a negative number to 0. The result is coming out with every transaction, so now I'm just trying to take each person's numbers, average them and then display them by user name.

Here is what I've got so far

```
SELECT [Transaction], [UserID], 
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF (day, [ShippingDt], [InvoiceDate]) < 0 
         THEN 0 
         ELSE DATEDIFF (day, [ShippingDt], [InvoiceDate])
       END AS DTC
FROM Transaction.table
WHERE [ShippingDt] >= '20211101' AND [ShippingDt] < '20211201'
  AND [InvoiceDate] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: That's a `case` _expression_.

Comment: A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you say you want an average, so `AVG` seems to be appropriate, and group by `UserID`:

```sql
SELECT [UserID], 
    AVG(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [ShippingDt], [InvoiceDate]) < 0 
         THEN 0 
         ELSE DATEDIFF(day, [ShippingDt], [InvoiceDate])
       END) AS DTC
FROM Transaction.table
WHERE [ShippingDt] >= '20211101' AND [ShippingDt] < '20211201'
  AND [InvoiceDate] IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY [UserID];
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to use AVG and was missing where i should drop the ) to close it as well as the GROUP BY.

Comment: @Mikeydipow Sure. You may want to do some reading on [Aggregate Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Also consider accepting the answer if you think it's an acceptable solution.

Comment: I've accepted the answer, thank you so much for the help!
Could i bug you to understand how I can use the AVG fun but display decimals? I used CAST to show decimals but it's only displaying them as 0's instead of the actual number.

Comment: @Mikeydipow It looks like the return type of `AVG` depends on the expression you give it. So you will have to use `AVG(CAST(CASE ... END AS decimal(19,4))) AS DTC`